# Cloudfront will serve my site WITHOUT www but not WITH www. Where can I adjust this?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I set up Cloudfront as a CDN for my site months ago, and it stopped working this week.

As context, I use a custom domain (like cdn.domain.com) to redirect to the cloudfront address via a CNAME entry in the DNS at my host.

Currently, this will work:

https://cdn.domain.com/cssfile.css

But, this will not work:

https://www.cdn.domain.com/cssfile.css

I need the latter to work.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure [Alternate Domain Names](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html) in CloudFront to make it aware of what domain names you want it to serve.

Comment: In the Alternate Domain Names section of the distribution, I have both versions listed (www.cdn.domain.com and cdn.domain.com). But, only the latter option will load. Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the DNS for the `www` has propagated? What does `traceroute` show for both?

Comment: The DNS has propogated. And, this is the traceroute result for the www version that won't work: "No IPv4 address could be found."

Comment: It sounds like the DNS has not in fact propagated if no IP address can be found by `traceroute`.

Comment: The CNAME entries for the www and non-www entries were created months ago (and haven't been edited since), so I don't think propogation is the issue. Is it possible there's another explanation?

Comment: What is the actual output from `traceroute`? If it finds a location for `cdn.whatever` but not `www.cdn.whatever` then there is a DNS configuration issue that needs to be researched. It's possible the `www.cdn` DNS record you think is correct actually has an incorrect value or something.

Comment: The DNS records are correct, but--when entering the www version into a CNAME tool like dnschecker, it doesn't point to the cloudfront installation. To that end, I think this is a DNS issue (rather than a AWS one). So, I deleted the CNAME entry and rebuilt it. Will let it propogated again and see if that resolves the issue. Thanks for helping me clarify the issue.